# Show that $ \left\| f- \sum_{k=1}^N c_kv_k \right\|^2 $ can be written as...

Tags: hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

Let $\mathcal{H}$ denote a separable Hilbert space, with orthonormal basis $\{v_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$. Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$, and consider the subspace $M := \text{span} \{v_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$.

Show that for any $f \in \mathcal{H}$ and any coefficients $c_1,...,c_N \in \mathbb{C}$,
\begin{equation*}
    \left\| f- \sum_{k=1}^N c_kv_k \right\|^2 = \sum_{k=1}^N |c_k - \langle f,v_k \rangle |^2 + \sum_{k=N+1}^\infty |\langle f,v_k \rangle |^2
\end{equation*}

My attempt so far
\begin{align}
\left\| f- \sum_{k=1}^N c_kv_k \right\|^2  & = \left\langle f- \sum_{k=1}^N c_kv_k, f- \sum_{k=1}^N c_kv_k \right\rangle \\
& = \left\langle f, f- \sum_{k=1}^N c_kv_k \right\rangle -\sum_{k=1}^N c_k \left\langle v_k, f- \sum_{k=1}^N c_kv_k \right\rangle \\
& = \langle f,f \rangle - \sum_{k=1}^N \overline{c}_k \langle f,v_k \rangle - \sum_{k=1}^N \overline{c}_k \langle v_k,f \rangle  + \sum_{k=1}^N \sum_{l=1}^N \overline{c}_l c_k  \langle v_k,v_l \rangle
\end{align}
I'm not really sure if I'm on the right track. Can somebody help me with the next step. Thanks.

Comment: By the definition of an orthonormal basis, there exists a sequence $ (\lambda_{k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \in {\ell^{2}}(\mathbb{N}) $ such that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}
\left\| f - \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \lambda_{k} v_{k} \right\|_{\mathcal{H}} = 0.
$$

Comment: **Hint:** Use [Parseval’s Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity).

Answer (score 1):

Since $\{v_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal H$,  [Parseval's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity) shows that for any vector $u$, the following equality holds:
$$
\left\lVert u\right\rVert^2=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left\lvert \left\langle u,v_k\right\rangle\right\rvert^2.
$$
Apply this to $u:= f-\sum_{i=1}^N c_iv_i$. Then for all $k\geqslant 1$, 
$$
  \left\langle u,v_k\right\rangle=\left\langle f,v_k\right\rangle
-\sum_{i=1}^N c_i\left\langle v_i,v_k\right\rangle.
$$
If $1\leqslant k\leqslant N$, then $\sum_{i=1}^N c_i\left\langle v_i,v_k\right\rangle=c_k$ hence $\left\lvert \left\langle u,v_k\right\rangle\right\rvert^2=\left\lvert \left\langle f,v_k\right\rangle-c_k\right\rvert^2$ and if $k\geqslant N+1$, then $\sum_{i=1}^N c_i\left\langle v_i,v_k\right\rangle=0$ hence 
$\left\lvert \left\langle u,v_k\right\rangle\right\rvert^2=\left\lvert \left\langle f,v_k\right\rangle \right\rvert^2$.